Spring Security: Finding User For Authentication With Hibernate and Spring Data JPA
I'm a beginner with Spring Boot/Security. I'm having trouble getting a user from MySQL db for authentication with my custom login page.
I have configured my custom UserDetailsService class, and I'm pretty sure my mapping with my SecurityConfig class works, but everytime I try logging in with an existing user in my database, with of the DEBUG logging errors always says "cannot find user ' '. This is the DEBUG message:
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.full_name,u1_0.password from user_info_table u1_0 where     u1_0.email=?
2024-04-08T17:36:56.795-04:00 DEBUG 28416 --- [Finance_Tracker] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to find user ''

It always brings me back to my login.html page since it never authenticates, but I want it to redirect to my dashboard page. Please help, I'd really appreciate it.Thanks!
SECURITY-CONFIG-CLASS:
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserInfoUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider dao = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        dao.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        dao.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return dao;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests( authorization -> authorization
                        .requestMatchers("/welcome", "/register", "/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/welcome/**").authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin( login -> login
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true)
                        .permitAll()
                );

        return http.build();
    }

}

CUSTOM USER-DETAILS-SERVICE-CLASS
@Component
public class UserInfoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserInfoUserDetailsService.class);


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        logger.debug("Attempting to load user by email: {}", email);

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with email: " + email));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(),
                Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
    }
}

USER MODEL CLASS:
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_info_table")
public class User {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

}

USER CONTROLLER
@Controller
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String displayWelcomePage() {
        return "welcome";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String displayRegistrationPage() {
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerUserToDatabase(@ModelAttribute User user, 
RedirectAttributes redirect) {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "Successful Registration!");
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/dashboard")
    public String displayDashboardPage() {
         return "dashboard";
     }
 }

04-09T14:40:45.533-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-09T14:40:54.251-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /login
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.full_name,u1_0.password from user_info_table u1_0 where u1_0.email=?
2024-04-09T14:40:55.090-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to find user ''
2024-04-09T14:40:55.090-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /login?error
2024-04-09T14:40:55.102-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login?error
2024-04-09T14:40:55.102-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login?error
2024-04-09T14:40:55.102-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login?error", parameters={masked}
2024-04-09T14:40:55.102-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.diazdevin.finance_tracker.controller.UserController#loginPage()
2024-04-09T14:40:55.102-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2024-04-09T14:40:55.106-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2024-04-09T14:40:55.106-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-09T14:40:55.200-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /favicon.ico
2024-04-09T14:40:55.205-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-09T14:40:55.206-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2024-04-09T14:40:55.215-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2024-04-09T14:40:55.215-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2024-04-09T14:40:55.215-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2024-04-09T14:40:55.215-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.diazdevin.finance_tracker.controller.UserController#loginPage()
2024-04-09T14:40:55.215-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected '*/*' given [image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, image/svg+xml, image/*, */*;q=0.8]
2024-04-09T14:40:55.215-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2024-04-09T14:40:55.215-04:00 DEBUG 21460 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

VIEW OF LOGIN PAGE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div th:if="${successMessage}">
        <p th:text="${successMessage}" style="color:green"></p>
    </div>

<form th:action="@{/login}" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL: : " required>
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="ENTER PASSWORD: " required>

    <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

NEW LOGS
2024-04-09T18:02:12.054-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-09T18:02:18.959-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login?email=steve7%40gmail.com&password=apple
2024-04-09T18:02:18.972-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login?email=steve7%40gmail.com&password=apple
2024-04-09T18:02:18.980-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login?email=steve7%40gmail.com&password=apple", parameters={masked}
2024-04-09T18:02:18.980-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.diazdevin.finance_tracker.controller.UserController#loginPage()
2024-04-09T18:02:18.980-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2024-04-09T18:02:18.980-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2024-04-09T18:02:18.980-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-09T18:02:19.048-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /favicon.ico
2024-04-09T18:02:19.048-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-09T18:02:19.048-04:00 DEBUG 29216 --- [Finance_Tracker] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login

network logs
image 1
image 2
post request image

@Toerktumlare The comment comes out terrible, I have this on my GitHub, I'll provide the link for it. I would really appreciate the help. Thank you. https://github.com/Devin-Diaz/Finance-Tracker

Does this answer your question? Spring Security 6 and JSP view rendering

im suspecting that your request is faulty and that you are sending an empty string. Are you sending proper FormData? dont send json

@Toerktumlare im using thymeleaf for my frontend, I just attached it to the problem. I changed where it said method= from post to get, and now it's not saying anymore that it's an empty String on an attempted login. I provided the new logs above as well

but what, thats to save user, thats not login, you said you had problem with login. You know what this is taking too much time, and your question is way to unclear. Good luck

@Toerktumlare I'm sorry you feel that way. You wanna tell me at least what I benefit from looking at the network tab so I can learn something new

to ensure that the request you are doing between the frontend and backend has the correct format.
